# codeigniter mail sending error 451

Tags: codeigniter, smtp, sendmail

Can any one tell me why I'm getting this error with codeigniter when it comes to sending mail.

some time it work fine some times i get this error

451 Please try again later
The following SMTP error was encountered: 451 Please try again later
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your SMTP server is working fine at the time you get this error? If it works sometimes, then that means that your configuration is probably fine. I'd deploy the code of a test server online and then run your code to see if its really a configuration problem or maybe a problem with the SMTP host that you're trying to send the mail through.

Comment: it's the same server as my mail server, even when this error occurs the mail server sill works. 

I'm actually connecting to my online host and via SMTP

Comment: Could you please share your SMTP settings that you're using to send mail in CodeIgniter? Also, how else are you testing your mail server to know whether its working fine or not?

Comment: I got it to work had to go back into the app change up the settings

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at Amazon SES for your mail needs. I just moved from using gmail's SMTP to Amazon SES, and it is way faster, easier to use and low overhead than SMTP. Plus, you are no longer dependent on server configurations for sending mail.